# How to get SonarQube reports cleared after removing a rule from project profile

Tags: sonarqube

In my team, we've recently reviewed our company-standard Java profile for SonarQube and we've decided to remove a couple of rules from it, for instance,

> Security constraints should be defined - S3369

The problem is that SonarQube 6.7 LTS dashboards still show the corresponding reports on our projects even though the rule is no longer in the profile.

Apart from bulk changing the issues as "Won't Fix" on each project of our portfolio, is it possible to clear reports that stem from rules that once were active but which are now deactivated?

Comment: a new analysis of each project should solve this issue for you

Comment: I should have thought of that! A new analysis did the trick.